# How to write code for mouse event?

Tags: events, mouse

I have a grid where i can select multiple item to another grid.Now my ques is if i select multiple item and when i double click it,so only the item on which the mouse focus should get selected.

Comment: What language / technologies etc?

Answer (score 0):

On the grid you are catching the double click event - see if you have a `SelectedXXX` property (e.g. `SelectedRows`, `SelectedCells`) - the name of the property would depend on the type of the grid.

Posting more information about the type of control you are using will give you more accurate answers.